# How to query colours, line width, line styles used in current plot?

Tags: r, plot

After a plot function is called it is possible to query the extent of the axes by using `par('usr')`, which yields a vector of the form "xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax", eg:

```
> plot(x=2:4, y=9:11, type='l', col='red', lty='dashed', lwd=5)
> par('usr')
[1]  1.92  4.08  8.92 11.08
```

Is there an analogous command to query the colours, line widths, and line types, and similarly for points, in the current plot?

I tried `par('col')` and `par('lty')`, but they don't yield what I'm looking for; eg:

```
> plot(x=2:4, y=9:11, type='l', col='red', lty='dashed', lwd=5)
> par('col') # yields 'black' but plot used 'red'
[1] "black"
> par('lty') # yields 'solid' but plot used 'dashed'
[1] "solid"
> par('lwd') # yields 1 but plot used 5
[1] 1
```

Thank you for any help about this.